# Append filenames of flowfiles in NiFi to CSV file

Tags: apache-nifi

First I use the listFile processor to list all files in a specific map. Then, I would like to append ${filename} of a flowfile in NiFi to an extern file example.csv. I thought about using ExecuteScript with Python, but don't know how to.

I tried the following:

Use two list processors, one for the map and one for example.csv file. replaceText processor to replace text to `${filename}`, `mergeContent`, and `putFile(replace example.csv)`. Works only the first time.

Comment: What does the map file look like? Is it a list of filenames that are to be merged into a single csv file?

Comment: Yes. For example /path/to/files/ contains three files example1.csv, example2.csv, example3.csv. I want those filenames to be in a single file called files.csv.

Comment: Why mergeContent only works the first time? If you are overwritting the examples.csv it is important that you read it also, otherwise you just append to it and clean what you have read

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteScript processor can be used, with the following script in python

```
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript 
import subprocess

flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile is not None:
     myCsvRow = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
     fd = open('/path/to/your/map/files.csv','a')
     fd.write(myCsvRow)
     fd.close()
     session.transfer(flowFile,ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: second line gives error message. by removing, it works perfectly.